# JS. Non-standard overlay over table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have visual selection for table which colorize mouse overed table cell and it row and column, like some crosshar.

see JSFiddle:

```
http:// jsfiddle.net/arhangelsoft/0ardb3u0/40/
```

But I'm need JS automated and animated movement with effects(like easing), like from 0,0 crosshair smooth moves to 55 cell, after that the same smooth moves to 22 cell and etc.

I thinking, how to do that.

Currently I have an idea:
Create absolute div for row(u see it in blue color), columns and target cell.
After that move theese elemets together in animate funtion from x point to y point.

Is there more simply method/idea to do it?

The similar example of result what I want get via JavaScript you can dewnload here(GIF picture, big(2 mb) ):
[download and see](http://rghost.ru/60363460)

sorry, I can't make it smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/0ardb3u0/41/

(I've commented out all your code as a reference, the new code is at the bottom of fiddle.)

You are right: the approach here is to actually create 2 absolute `div`s and to move them according to hovered cell.

For the animation we can use CSS `transition` property here:

```
transition: all 0.1s linear
```

...so that when we do `$(...).css(...)` changing its `width`, `height`, `top` and `bottom`, properties are transitioned smoothly from old value to new one.
You can still use `jQuery`'s `$.animate()` method for the animation, but CSS transitions are basically much more faster and smoother.

Also, note that I've used `$(...).outerWidth(...)` instead of `width(...)` to properly resize cells.

One more thing: note this CSS line -

```
pointer-events: none;
```

It is very important because it makes the crosshair divs 'transparent' for mouse events, meaning actual clicks will go "through" them and will be captured by appropriate `td` element.

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks! Ihave no matter that's will be too simple! Hmm, yes without animate it will be better. I use trigger to make robot movements from 55 cell to 71 cell. But It not work or work too fast, why? see http://jsfiddle.net/arhangelsoft/0ardb3u0/42/

Comment: @AlexLL to move crosshair to some column, just trigger its mouseenter event: `$('#cell_71').trigger('mouseover');`

Comment: I doing that here http://jsfiddle.net/arhangelsoft/0ardb3u0/43/ but not work(stops on 55 and not go to 71), or goes visually very fast.

Comment: something like that `$("#pole_table #cell_55").trigger("mouseover").delay(200).("#pole_table #cell_71").trigger("mouseover");` but not work.

Comment: @AlexLL just use `window.setTimeout()` instead of `delay()`: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/0ardb3u0/44/. I also changed transition time from `0.1s` to `0.5s`

Comment: @AlexLL you're welcome! If the answer satisfies you, I'll be very grateful if you mark the answer as `accepted`. Thanks!